# Matrix Vector Multiplication and Cancellation

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a very basic question, but unfortunately I cannot find an answer to it. Let $A$ and $B$ be square invertible $n \times n$ matrices. Let $\vec c$ be an $n \times 1$ vector.

If we have

$ A\vec c = B\vec c$

does $A = B$ ? Does $\vec c$ cancel in a sense?

If it depends on some conditions, under what general conditions is it true?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think about what happens when $\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{0}$. Also, you can rewrite the equation as $(A-B)\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{0}$. Does $A$ and $B$ being invertible guarantee anything about $A-B$?

Comment: Hi @Shoda, thanks for the comment. I suppose the invertibility of A and B guarantees that $A - B$ is invertible. Not quite sure what to do from there.

Comment: Are you sure that $A$ and $B$ invertible implies $A-B$ is invertible? Also, think about the case that $\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: @MushedBananas Is $A - B$ invertible if $A = B$?

Comment: In case his comment wasn't clear, $A$ and $B$ invertible does **not** imply $A-B$ is invertible.  Take for trivial counterexample when $A=B$.  Take for less trivial counterexample when $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\1&3\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  You have in this case the first column of $A-B$ is made up only of zeroes and trivially has determinant equal to zero.

Comment: As JMoravitz wrote, in general no. They only need to behave equally in the dimensions they project the vector onto.

Comment: Thank you guys, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Both $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ are invertible, however they are nonequal.

This acts as a counterexample to the claim above.  $Ac=Bc$ with $A$ and $B$ invertible does **not** imply that $A=B$

Comment: Thank you. I only just started with linear algebra and my mind's really stuck at the moment. That definitely clears it up! Thank you so much!

Comment: As an aside, if you change the condition to $Ac=Bc$ for **all** $c$ (as opposed to just for *some* $c$), then that would imply $A=B$, since that implies $(A-B)c=0$ for all $c$, so $(A-B)$ is of rank zero, implying $A-B$ is the zero matrix, implying $A=B$.